# Parse XML using XMLDocument

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am trying to parse an XML file that is setup like so:

```
<root>
<Section category="Device_Type" CodeLength="1">
    <item code="C">Cart</item>
    <item code="D">Desktop</item>
    <item code="L">Laptop</item>
    <item code="T">Tablets</item>
    <item code="V">Virtual</item>
    <item code="R">Robobox</item>
</Section>
<Section category="Building" CodeLength="3">
    <item code="1PE">Address</item>
    <item code="SL1">Address</item>
    <item code="LR1">Address</item>
    <item code="LL8">Address</item>
    ...
</Section>
```

I have been following this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4826/XML-File-Parsing-in-VB-NET

I can read the file, and I figured out how to get all of the item nodes, however **I can't figure out how to get the items that are in a single section**.

For example, I am trying to get all items that are in the section where the category is Building.

This is what I have so far...

```
    Private Sub TabItem_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim XMLDoc As New Xml.XmlDocument
    Dim Nodelist As Xml.XmlNodeList
    Dim Node As Xml.XmlNode

    XMLDoc.Load("\\ukhcdata\share\ITS Shared Files\Rename Computer XML\NamingStandardsCode.xml")
    Nodelist = XMLDoc.SelectNodes("/root/Section/item")

    For Each Node In Nodelist
        Dim itemCode = Node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("code").Value
        MsgBox(itemCode.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: you need to filter by section where section attribute is = to Building

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a cleaner way using XPath only to filter node by attribute :

```
Nodelist = XMLDoc.SelectNodes("/root/Section[@category='Building']/item")

For Each Node In Nodelist
    Dim itemCode = Node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("code").Value
    MsgBox(itemCode.ToString)
Next
```

Comment: Wow. That is so easy.  I thought there had to be a way to specify inline, but I didn't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment from makemone2010, I did find a working solution.

I'm not sure if there is a better way but it works.

```
    Private Sub TabItem_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim XMLDoc As New Xml.XmlDocument
    Dim Nodelist As Xml.XmlNodeList
    Dim Node As Xml.XmlNode

    XMLDoc.Load("\\ukhcdata\share\ITS Shared Files\Rename Computer XML\NamingStandardsCode.xml")
    Nodelist = XMLDoc.SelectNodes("/root/Section/item")

    For Each Node In Nodelist
        If Node.ParentNode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("category").Value = "Building" Then
            Dim itemCode = Node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("code").Value
            MsgBox(itemCode.ToString)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of options. One possibility is to use [LINQ2XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763068.aspx), which allows powerful constructs in VB.NET:

```
    Dim xml = <root>
    <Section category="Device_Type" CodeLength="1">
        <item code="C">Cart</item>
        <item code="D">Desktop</item>
        <item code="L">Laptop</item>
        <item code="T">Tablets</item>
        <item code="V">Virtual</item>
        <item code="R">Robobox</item>
    </Section>
    <Section category="Building" CodeLength="3">
        <item code="1PE">Address</item>
        <item code="SL1">Address</item>
        <item code="LR1">Address</item>
        <item code="LL8">Address</item>
    </Section>
</root>
    ' take correct section
    dim section = (from e in xml.Elements("Section") where e.Attribute("category").Value = "Building").FirstOrDefault()
    for each node in section.Elements("item")
        Console.WriteLine(node.Attribute("code").Value)
    next node
```

The output is:

```
1PE
SL1
LR1
LL8
```

If you want to load the XML structure from a file, use [XDocument.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
    dim xml = XDocument.Load("c:\path\file.xml")
    ' take correct section
    dim section = (from e in xml.Elements("Section") where e.Attribute("category").Value = "Building").FirstOrDefault()
    for each node in section.Elements("item")
        Console.WriteLine(node.Attribute("code").Value)
    next node
```